How to open video while downloading like TikTok and YouTube using React Native
Is there a way to open the video file while it is downloading and watch all that is downloaded, one megabyte or more, using React WinTap?
Is there a way to open the video file while it is downloading and watch all that is downloaded,

If you have direct downloadable link or stream link authentication free like-->
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4
then with this package --> react-native-video
 <Video
       controls = {true}
       source = {
                 {
                   uri: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4"
                 }
                }

       resizeMode = "contain" />

-----or if the link required authentication then
<Video
    controls = { true }
    source = {
      {
        uri: `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4?[params]
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      }
    }

    resizeMode = "contain" />


How can I have a stream download link for my clips located in backet storng Google Cloud

This is not an answer.
